# Rails: Where should I put this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have multiple models in my application for different types of content, and I frequently need to get whichever one was most recently published. At the moment, I'm using `helper_method :latest_content` in my application controller.

Is this the best place to put this method? If so, how should I write rspec tests for it?

Comment: Please show the code for your multiple models and also the `latest_content ` method.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a common functionality across multiple models. Rails has `concerns` which allow you to do that.

```
# app/models/concerns/searchable.rb
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def last_content
      # ... here whatever is the content of :last_content
    end
  end
end 


# app/models/model_x.rb
class ModelX < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable
  ...
end

# app/models/model_y.rb
class ModelY < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like just the thing I need. I'll look into Concerns.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding Concerns just yet -- it sounds like this just adds common functionality into the models? Then, if I wanted to find the latest content, I'd need to do something like `Article.last.latest_content`, even though this may return a `Blog` or other class? (To clarify, I need to know the most recent content across _all_ of my models. Not just within each one.) Ideally, I'd like to be able to call `link_to latest_content`.

Comment: Yes. Concerns are used for common models functionalities. E.g. Searchable, Commentable, Rateable, etc. If you want to have a method that returns the overall `latest_content` across various models you could use either a new model class (perhaps containing other common methods to the same models) or an helper. I generally try to keep less code as possible in the helpers.